# How do I change the record separator in a text file?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to read in a file with names and addreses.  It may look like this:

```
John Doe
123 Main Street
My Town, US 12345

Ralph Kramden
c/o Joe
999 North Lane
YourTown, US 22839
```

Where there is always a line between records.  But I don't know how to tell Perl that the next X lines are all one record.  (And X can vary).

How can that be done?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

> `$/`
>   The input record separator, newline by default.  This
>   influences Perl’s idea of what a "line" is.  Works like awk’s
>   RS variable, including treating empty lines as a terminator if
>   set to the null string.  (An empty line cannot contain any
>   spaces or tabs.)  You may set it to a multi‐character string to
>   match a multi‐character terminator, or to "undef" to read
>   through the end of file.  Setting it to "\n\n" means something
>   slightly different than setting to "", if the file contains
>   consecutive empty lines.  Setting to "" will treat two or more
>   consecutive empty lines as a single empty line.  Setting to
>   "\n\n" will blindly assume that the next input character
>   belongs to the next paragraph, even if it’s a newline.
>   (Mnemonic: / delimits line boundaries when quoting poetry.)

So try this:

```
{
  open my $fh, "<", $input_file;
  local $/ = "";
  while(<$fh>) {
    # each loop, $_ will be a different record
    # the first will be "John Doe\n123 Main Street\nMy Town, US 12345\n\n"
    # etc.
  }
}
```

Comment: One nice thing is that, as said in the `perldoc` quote, you can set it to `"\n\n"` to skip one blank line, or `"\n\n\n"` to skip two blank lines, or `""` to skip any number of blank lines, which lets you build a more lenient "parser", which usually makes other people's lives easier.

Answer (score 2):

```
$/ = "";
```

to treat empty line as "record separator".